# How to plot matplotlib objects from third party libraries in streamlit?

Tags: python, matplotlib, streamlit

I am using a library called `toad` from [toad for WOE](https://toad.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html) and a function (bin_plot()) in it returns plot type - `<AxesSubplot: xlabel='mob2', ylabel='prop'>`

When I used this in `notebook` I am able to get the plot But I am unable to plot it in **streamlit**

(Have **Updated** the Post with `sample dataset & code` at the bottom of this post)

In Notebook:
[image]

Tried couple of things in `streamlit` as mentioned below which didn't work-

```
st.pyplot(bin_plot(X_train_binned,x=X_train_binned.columns[1],target='status_perf_end'))
```

Error: AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'

```
binned_1, ax = plt.subplots()
bin_plot(X_train_binned,x=X_train_binned.columns[1],target='status_perf_end')
st.pyplot(binned_1)
```

[image]

```
fig_binned = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
bin_plot(X_train_binned,x=X_train_binned.columns[1],target='status_perf_end')
st.pyplot(fig_binned)
```

Plots nothing

**UPDATE:**

Now when I just added `st.pyplot()` under the above code then I got this plot with an error:
[image]

I am not sure how to get this plot in streamlit error free. Would Appreciate any help.

**UPDATE** Adding code for sample dataset

```
from sklearn import datasets

iris_data = datasets.load_iris()
iris_df = pd.DataFrame(data = iris_data['data'], columns = iris_data['feature_names'])
iris_df['Iris_type'] = iris_data['target']

# keeping it to 2 types only and removing 3rd category
iris_df = iris_df.loc[iris_df.Iris_type != 2]

# importing toad lib
from toad.plot import bin_plot

# plotting from data
bin_plot(iris_df, iris_df.columns[0], target='Iris_type')

# I would like to run this bin_plot() in streamlit
```

Answer (score 0):

`st.pyplot` allows you to display `pyplot` figures, but it seems like the `bin_plot` isn't returning a `pyplot` figure. If Toad supports converting what's returned by `bin_plot()` to HTML, you could then use `st.markdown` to display the plot.

`st.markdown(html_string, unsafe_allow_html=True)`

Comment: Thanks Caroline but I am getting an error when trying to write it to html `AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'write_html'`